# Keep getting the Set the topViewController before loading ECSlidingViewController error

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have been following the video tutorial(s) at these links: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJJMyzdB9uI, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqFFjmhoO1c. I placed the code in my initial view controllers' viewDidLoad method to make a mainviewcontroller the top view controller but i keep getting this error "Set the topViewController before loading ECSlidingViewController". I don't get the reason for this error and didn't find much when i google'd it. Any ideas?

Here is the code i put into my viewDidLoad method, the application crashes before the uiviews even load.

```
self.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on some documentation from the developer. I didn't expect this library to be documented this way.

You have to add user defined values into your main sliding view controller. The main sliding view controller would be the one that extends or inheirits the ECSlidingViewController.

https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/wiki/Storyboards-Guide